# Unable to open website with Android WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

Trying to load [this website](https://sapsnkra.moe.gov.my/ibubapa2/index.php) with WebView, but it just show a blank page.

I can open other website with no problem, but not the above website. Possible the web developer block it? The website is not owned by me.

```
    guideView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.guideView);

    guideView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    guideView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    guideView.loadUrl("https://sapsnkra.moe.gov.my/ibubapa2/index.php");

}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                              Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
}
```

I tried to `setWebChromeClient`, but it do not work as well.

Comment: Issue is with the url you are trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

This link is apparently is blocked to access. I tried to access and dont work.

Make sure this .php is working to network access. As it is a .gov url there may be blocks.